# Как избежать цикла в цикле?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Разрабатываю, казалось бы, простую вещь, как электронное расписание пар. 
Цель: при выборе верхней/нижней недели - скрывать соответствующие пары.
Проблема: если сначала выбрать верхнюю неделю, а затем нижнюю, то почти все пары скроются. Я понимаю, что при выборе нижней недели, парам с верхней нужно заново добавлять класс 'block', но следовательно необходимо заново циклом перебрать NodeList. 
Вопрос: как избежать подобной ситуации? Строки кода 13-16

```js
let selectWeeks = document.querySelector('#week');


selectWeeks.onclick = () => {
    let doubleSubject = document.querySelectorAll('.double-subj');
    let firstSubjects = document.querySelectorAll('.first-subj');

    if (selectWeeks.selectedIndex == 1) {
        doubleSubject.forEach(element => {
            element.style.display = 'none';
        });
    }
    else if (selectWeeks.selectedIndex == 2) {
        firstSubjects.forEach(element => {
            element.style.display = 'none';
        });
    }
};
```

```css
.days {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.time {
    padding: 10px;
}
p {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Расписание Пинф 19</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Расписание</h1>
    <p>Неделя:</p>
    <select name="week" id="week">
        <option value="0">Выбери неделю</option>
        <option value="1">Верхняя</option>
        <option value="1">Нижняя</option>
    </select>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody>
            <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th class="days" colspan="2" >Понедельник</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="time table-warning">Время</th>
            <th align="left" class="table-warning">Предметы</th>
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
            <th class="table-info">08:30 - 10:00</th>
            <td class="">Математическое и имитационное моделирование (практ.)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="table-info">10:15 - 11:45</th>
            <td class="">Информационная безопасность (лекц.)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">12:10 - 13:40</th>
            <td class="first-subj">Теория вероятностей и математическая статистика (сем.) </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="double-subj">Электронный бизнес на международном рынке товаров и услуг (лекц.)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">13:55 - 15:25</th>
            <td class="first-subj">Программная инженерия (практ.)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="double-subj">Теория вероятностей и математическая статистика (сем.)</td>
        </tr>
        <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th class="days" colspan="2">Вторник</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">08:30 - 10:00</th>
            <td class="first-subj">Системы поддержки принятия решений (практ.)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="double-subj">Программная инженерия (практ.)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="table-info">10:15 - 11:45</th>
            <td>Теория вероятностей и математическая статистика (лекц.)</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
             <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">12:10 - 13:40</th>
             <td class="first-subj">Электронный бизнес на международном рынке товаров и услуг</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td class="double-subj">Математическое и имитационное моделирование (лекц.)</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">13:55 - 15:25</th>
             <td class="first-subj">-  </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td class="double-subj">Базы данных (практ.)</td>
         </tr>
        <thead class="thead-light">
         <tr>
            <th class="days" colspan="2" >Среда</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">08:30 - 10:00</th>
            <td class="first-subj">Исследование операций и методы оптимизации (лекц.)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="double-subj">Информационная безопасность (практ.)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">10:15 - 11:45</th>
            <td class="first-subj">Программная инженерия (лекц.)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="double-subj">Проектирование информационных систем (практ.)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">12:10 - 13:40</th>
            <td class="first-subj">Экономика и организация предприятия (сем.)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="double-subj">Информационные системы и технологии (лекц.)</td>
        </tr>
        <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th class="days" colspan="2">Четверг</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="table-info">08:30 - 10:00</th>
            <td>Информационные системы и технологии (сем.)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">10:15 - 11:45</th>
            <td class="first-subj">Система поддержки принятия решений (лекц.)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="double-subj">Экономика и организация предприятия (сем.)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="table-info">12:10 - 13:40</th>
            <td>Электронный бизнес на международном рынке товаров и услуг (сем.)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">13:55 - 15:25</th>
            <td class="first-subj">Проектирование информационных систем (практ.)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="double-subj">Базы данных (лекц.)</td>
        </tr>
        <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th class="days" colspan="2">Пятница</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">08:30 - 10:00</th>
            <td class="first-subj">Экономика и организация предприятия (лекц.)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="double-subj">Проектирование информационных систем (лекц.)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="table-info">10:15 - 11:45</th>
            <td>Исследование операций и методы оптимизации (сем.)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">12:10 - 13:40</th>
            <td class="first-subj">Базы данных (лекц.)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="double-subj">Системы поддержки принятия решений (сем.)</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>


    <script src="./js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не надо бояться циклов... JS выполняет их примерно... `писец как быстро` !) Миллионы итераций - раз плюнуть. Если смущает количество кода, можно записать две универсальных функции, которые будут получать элемент/список элементов и скрывать или показывать их... но всё равно используя перебор.

```js
let selectWeeks = document.getElementById('week');

let classes = [
  document.querySelectorAll('.first-subj'),
  document.querySelectorAll('.double-subj'),
];

// Если использовать обычную функцию, а не стрелочную, 
// this будет указывать на элемент, который запустил функцию (селект). Что удобно.
selectWeeks.addEventListener('change', function() {
  let index = this.value - 1; // получится или 0 или 1
  let other = Math.pow( 0, index ); 
  // просто ради прикола. Здесь надо взять все остальные элементы массива кроме index
  // 0 в степени 0 будет 1, а 0 в степени 1 будет 0))

  let toShow = classes[index];
  if( toShow ){
    hide( classes[other] );
    show( toShow );
  }
});

/***************/

function hide(elems) {
  if (elems instanceof HTMLElement) {
    elems.style.display = "none";
    return;
  }
  Array.from(elems).forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
}

function show(elems, display) {
  display = display || 'block';
  if (elems instanceof HTMLElement) {
    elems.style.display = display;
    return;
  }
  Array.from(elems).forEach(e => e.style.display = display);
}
```

```css
.days {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.time {
  padding: 10px;
}

p {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<h1>Расписание</h1>
<p>Неделя:</p>
<select name="week" id="week">
  <option value="0">Выбери неделю</option>
  <option value="1">Верхняя</option>
  <option value="2">Нижняя</option>
</select>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <thead class="thead-light">
      <tr>
        <th class="days" colspan="2">Понедельник</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="time table-warning">Время</th>
      <th align="left" class="table-warning">Предметы</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th class="table-info">08:30 - 10:00</th>
      <td class="">Математическое и имитационное моделирование (практ.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="table-info">10:15 - 11:45</th>
      <td class="">Информационная безопасность (лекц.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">12:10 - 13:40</th>
      <td class="first-subj">Теория вероятностей и математическая статистика (сем.) </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="double-subj">Электронный бизнес на международном рынке товаров и услуг (лекц.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">13:55 - 15:25</th>
      <td class="first-subj">Программная инженерия (практ.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="double-subj">Теория вероятностей и математическая статистика (сем.)</td>
    </tr>
    <thead class="thead-light">
      <tr>
        <th class="days" colspan="2">Вторник</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">08:30 - 10:00</th>
      <td class="first-subj">Системы поддержки принятия решений (практ.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="double-subj">Программная инженерия (практ.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="table-info">10:15 - 11:45</th>
      <td>Теория вероятностей и математическая статистика (лекц.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">12:10 - 13:40</th>
      <td class="first-subj">Электронный бизнес на международном рынке товаров и услуг</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="double-subj">Математическое и имитационное моделирование (лекц.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">13:55 - 15:25</th>
      <td class="first-subj">- </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="double-subj">Базы данных (практ.)</td>
    </tr>
    <thead class="thead-light">
      <tr>
        <th class="days" colspan="2">Среда</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">08:30 - 10:00</th>
      <td class="first-subj">Исследование операций и методы оптимизации (лекц.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="double-subj">Информационная безопасность (практ.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">10:15 - 11:45</th>
      <td class="first-subj">Программная инженерия (лекц.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="double-subj">Проектирование информационных систем (практ.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">12:10 - 13:40</th>
      <td class="first-subj">Экономика и организация предприятия (сем.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="double-subj">Информационные системы и технологии (лекц.)</td>
    </tr>
    <thead class="thead-light">
      <tr>
        <th class="days" colspan="2">Четверг</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="table-info">08:30 - 10:00</th>
      <td>Информационные системы и технологии (сем.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">10:15 - 11:45</th>
      <td class="first-subj">Система поддержки принятия решений (лекц.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="double-subj">Экономика и организация предприятия (сем.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="table-info">12:10 - 13:40</th>
      <td>Электронный бизнес на международном рынке товаров и услуг (сем.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">13:55 - 15:25</th>
      <td class="first-subj">Проектирование информационных систем (практ.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="double-subj">Базы данных (лекц.)</td>
    </tr>
    <thead class="thead-light">
      <tr>
        <th class="days" colspan="2">Пятница</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">08:30 - 10:00</th>
      <td class="first-subj">Экономика и организация предприятия (лекц.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="double-subj">Проектирование информационных систем (лекц.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="table-info">10:15 - 11:45</th>
      <td>Исследование операций и методы оптимизации (сем.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">12:10 - 13:40</th>
      <td class="first-subj">Базы данных (лекц.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="double-subj">Системы поддержки принятия решений (сем.)</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Не надо изобретать велосипед и делать то, что браузер может сделать сам. Просто вешаешь какой-нибудь класс на таблицу и в css скрываешь лишнее.

```js
document.getElementById('week').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var cl = document.getElementById('schedule').classList

  cl.remove('top-only')
  cl.remove('bottom-only')
  cl.add(e.target.value)
})
```

```css
.days {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.time {
  padding: 10px;
}

.top-only .double-subj, .bottom-only .first-subj {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<h1>Расписание</h1>
<p>Неделя:</p>
<select name="week" id="week">
  <option value="both">Выбери неделю</option>
  <option value="top-only">Верхняя</option>
  <option value="bottom-only">Нижняя</option>
</select>
<table id="schedule" class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <thead class="thead-light">
      <tr>
        <th class="days" colspan="2">Понедельник</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="time table-warning">Время</th>
      <th align="left" class="table-warning">Предметы</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th class="table-info">08:30 - 10:00</th>
      <td class="">Математическое и имитационное моделирование (практ.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="table-info">10:15 - 11:45</th>
      <td class="">Информационная безопасность (лекц.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">12:10 - 13:40</th>
      <td class="first-subj">Теория вероятностей и математическая статистика (сем.) </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="double-subj">Электронный бизнес на международном рынке товаров и услуг (лекц.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">13:55 - 15:25</th>
      <td class="first-subj">Программная инженерия (практ.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="double-subj">Теория вероятностей и математическая статистика (сем.)</td>
    </tr>
    <thead class="thead-light">
      <tr>
        <th class="days" colspan="2">Вторник</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">08:30 - 10:00</th>
      <td class="first-subj">Системы поддержки принятия решений (практ.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="double-subj">Программная инженерия (практ.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="table-info">10:15 - 11:45</th>
      <td>Теория вероятностей и математическая статистика (лекц.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">12:10 - 13:40</th>
      <td class="first-subj">Электронный бизнес на международном рынке товаров и услуг</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="double-subj">Математическое и имитационное моделирование (лекц.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">13:55 - 15:25</th>
      <td class="first-subj">- </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="double-subj">Базы данных (практ.)</td>
    </tr>
    <thead class="thead-light">
      <tr>
        <th class="days" colspan="2">Среда</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">08:30 - 10:00</th>
      <td class="first-subj">Исследование операций и методы оптимизации (лекц.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="double-subj">Информационная безопасность (практ.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">10:15 - 11:45</th>
      <td class="first-subj">Программная инженерия (лекц.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="double-subj">Проектирование информационных систем (практ.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">12:10 - 13:40</th>
      <td class="first-subj">Экономика и организация предприятия (сем.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="double-subj">Информационные системы и технологии (лекц.)</td>
    </tr>
    <thead class="thead-light">
      <tr>
        <th class="days" colspan="2">Четверг</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="table-info">08:30 - 10:00</th>
      <td>Информационные системы и технологии (сем.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">10:15 - 11:45</th>
      <td class="first-subj">Система поддержки принятия решений (лекц.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="double-subj">Экономика и организация предприятия (сем.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="table-info">12:10 - 13:40</th>
      <td>Электронный бизнес на международном рынке товаров и услуг (сем.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">13:55 - 15:25</th>
      <td class="first-subj">Проектирование информационных систем (практ.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="double-subj">Базы данных (лекц.)</td>
    </tr>
    <thead class="thead-light">
      <tr>
        <th class="days" colspan="2">Пятница</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">08:30 - 10:00</th>
      <td class="first-subj">Экономика и организация предприятия (лекц.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="double-subj">Проектирование информационных систем (лекц.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="table-info">10:15 - 11:45</th>
      <td>Исследование операций и методы оптимизации (сем.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" class="table-info">12:10 - 13:40</th>
      <td class="first-subj">Базы данных (лекц.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="double-subj">Системы поддержки принятия решений (сем.)</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```